# FIltrar en SQL Server para calcular

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

Estoy trabajando en un ejercicio el cual solicita que filtren informacion y que haga calculos respecto a algunos de los valores que hay en su columnas y estos a la vez tiene condiciones.

Aqui estan las caracteristicas de la tabla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Igualmente comparto los datos de la tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

HAy unos cuantos requisitos que se requiere de la tabla los cuales son que se calculen los ingresos por cada cliente basandose en esto:

- Tipo = BUY, el cliente compro algo y esto es un ingreso
- Tipo = SELL, el cliente vende algo y la compañia cobra el 10% de la transaccion

Los estatus determinan como se trata la transaccion:

- Estatus = COMPLETED, la transaccion se concluye normalmente
- Estatus = PENDING, la transaccion se ignora
- Estatus = CANCELED, la transaccion es nula y 1% de la cantidad de la transaccion es deducido del ingreso

Se requiere de una tabla que calcule el ingreso de compra y venta de cada uno de los clientes y mostrar una tabla como la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi duda es como puedo filtrar la informacion de cada cliente y realizar los calculos apropiados. No he encontrado alguna forma efectiva para solucionar este problema, espero contar con sus ayuda.

Aqui esta el codigo para crear la tabla:

```
create table transactions_2 (
    dt VARCHAR(19),
    customer VARCHAR(64),
    type_trans VARCHAR(4),
    amount DECIMAL(4,2),
    status VARCHAR(9)
);
```

Y para llenar la tabla tengo estos datos:

```
INSERT INTO transactions_2 VALUES 
('2021-07-09 20:03:14','rclaypole0@qq.com','BUY',71.46,'CANCELED'),
('2021-07-09 19:30:03','asmithin4@elegantthemes.com','SELL',40.24,'CANCELED'),
('2021-07-06 04:56:06','rclaypole0@qq.com','SELL',69.35,'PENDING'),
('2021-07-16 04:36:58','rclaypole0@qq.com','SELL',3.37,'CANCELED'),
('2021-07-15 11:59:36','bhaddeston2@mapquest.com','BUY',15.46,'CANCELED'),
('2021-07-24 16:31:04','bhaddeston2@mapquest.com','SELL',90.16,'COMPLETED'),
('2021-06-23 21:50:34','rclaypole0@qq.com','BUY',53.40,'CANCELED'),
('2021-07-30 22:30:22','bhaddeston2@mapquest.com','SELL',6.48,'PENDING'),
('2021-06-28 05:47:45','stapenden1@google.de','SELL',72.67,'PENDING'),
('2021-07-11 16:51:06','stapenden1@google.de','BUY',93.29,'CANCELED'),
('2021-07-16 08:25:11','rclaypole0@qq.com','BUY',53.19,'PENDING'),
('2021-07-22 02:24:59','rclaypole0@qq.com','BUY',51.17,'CANCELED'),
('2021-06-23 21:42:24','bhaddeston2@mapquest.com','SELL',10.57,'PENDING'),
('2021-07-22 09:11:56','rclaypole0@qq.com','BUY',68.25,'COMPLETED'),
('2021-07-19 04:11:50','rclaypole00@qq.com','SELL',66.78,'PENDING'),
('2021-07-03 19:00:10','gnickerson3@globo.com','BUY',26.31,'PENDING'),
('2021-07-11 17:56:06','bhaddeston2@mapquest.com','BUY',86.05,'CANCELED'),
('2021-07-03 01:58:09','stapenden1@google.de','SELL',31.49,'CANCELED'),
('2021-06-30 22:03:17','bhaddeston2@mapquest.com','BUY',50.93,'PENDING'),
('2021-07-09 14:22:39','stapenden1@google.de','BUY',5.40,'CANCELED');
```

Comment: hola, para que podamos darte una respuesta correcta es necesario en ocasiones que incluyas código para la creación de la tabla y el llenado de datos, de esta forma podemos hacer un copy/paste y tener una buena parte adelantada. No me queda claro que quieres decir con lo de "filtrar", comparte tu código y lo tendremos más claro

Comment: Claro, una disculpa es mi primer pregunta aqui asi que no estoy muy familiarizado con la etiqueta pero igualmente actualizare el post con el codigo para la creacion y para meter los datos. Y cuando me refiero a filtrarlos me refiero a juntar solo los buy y sell de cada cliente para que seguido de eso pueda hacer el calculo dependiendo de si es un BUY completado o CANCELADO o un SELL completado o cancelado. Espero tu apoyo gracias!

Answer (score 0):

> Te dejo el [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e0acad943cc10f5b047dfa2c81da6182)

La consulta restante es la siguiente:

```sql
SELECT  customer, 

ISNULL((SELECT SUM(amount) 
FROM MOCK_DATA 
WHERE customer=MG.customer AND typejo='BUY'), 0) BUY, 

ISNULL((SELECT SUM(amount) 
FROM MOCK_DATA 
WHERE customer=MG.customer AND typejo='SELL'), 0) SELL,

(ISNULL((
SELECT SUM(amount) 
FROM MOCK_DATA 
WHERE customer=MG.customer AND typejo='BUY'), 0) - 

ISNULL((
SELECT SUM(amount) 
FROM MOCK_DATA 
WHERE customer=MG.customer AND typejo='SELL'), 0)) TOTAL

FROM MOCK_DATA MG
GROUP BY customer
```

También se puede haber usado `PIVOT` para esto, pero yo lo resolví de la siguiente manera:

- Agrupando por la columna `customer`.
- Usando sub-querys para obtener las nuevas columnas `BUY` y `SELL`.
- La columna `TOTAL` se puede hacer usando variables locales, pero eso lo puedes seguir mejorando tú.

Comment: Tu SELECT me ayudo basntante, muchas gracias. Para que pueda seleccionar los datos si esta completado o cancelada una transaccion recomendarias que utilize CASES? Espero tu feedback

Comment: Pasa que con el CASE vas a obtener un valor que depende de una condición `(CASE WHEN condicion THEN valor1 ELSE valor2 END)`; sin embargo, tu ya tienes los valores que deseas obtener (CANCELED, COMPLETED, PENDING) solo hace faltaría que implementes la condición a tu consulta, como bien puede ser un `WHERE`

Comment: Entonces tendria que hacer estos queries pero agregandoles el WHERE y de ahi agregarle la multiplicacion del porcentaje a tomar?

Comment: ¿Por qué leer la tabla 5 veces cuando se puede leer una sola vez? Es totalmente ineficiente.

Answer (score 0):

Hacer esto es muy fácil mediante agregados condicionales. Solamente tienes que poner la expresión que necesites dentro de la función de agregado y puedes hacer todo leyendo la tabla una sola vez.

Para hacer las cosas más sencillas, generé una tabla virtual de factores que se aplican según el estatus de la operación.

```
SELECT customer,
    ROUND( SUM( CASE WHEN type_trans = 'BUY'  THEN amount * factor ELSE 0 END), 2) AS buy,
    ROUND( SUM( CASE WHEN type_trans = 'SELL' THEN amount * factor * .1 ELSE 0 END), 2) AS sell,
    ROUND( SUM( CASE WHEN type_trans = 'BUY'  THEN amount * factor 
                     WHEN type_trans = 'SELL' THEN amount * factor * .1 ELSE 0 END), 2) AS total
FROM transactions_2 t
JOIN (SELECT 'COMPLETED' AS status, 1.   AS factor UNION ALL
      SELECT 'PENDING'   AS status, 0.   AS factor UNION ALL
      SELECT 'CANCELED'  AS status, -.01 AS factor) AS f ON t.status = f.status
GROUP BY customer;
```